# NINA sister of siri

Tags: ios6, voice-recognition

I have read that nuance has introduced a voice recognition software "NINA" which is known as the sister of siri (which is the voice recognition software used in newer version of apple).nina is an open source api where we can use it for our individual app for voice recognition.i cant find any link for downloading this api so that i can use it in my app.
  anyone kindly suggest me some links for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might get something on this site
http://www.nuance.com/landing-pages/enterprise/meet-nina/default.asp

and do check out their original site too
http://www.nuance.com/index.htm